# How do I use ok Google with SoundHound?

Tags: google-now, ok-google

If I ask "ok Google, what song is this?"  it will tell me. 
However, I prefer to use SoundHound (because I have the paid version, and it stores my searches for later retrieval, and it links to spotify automatically).

Is there a voice command that asks "ok Google, ask SoundHound what song this is"?

I can't even seem to open the app." open SoundHound" yields a Google now result screen (where the first result is the app itself), but it does not open it -  probably because the paid app name is "SoundHound infinity " (the symbol for infinity).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you don't have such command right now. But you can expect it to be added in the future. Google is already working on it. More information [here](http://insidesearch.blogspot.co.uk/2015/01/google-app-update-get-now-cards-from.html).

Comment: I remember reading this a few weeks ago - but isn't this blog post for the cards? I would have assumed that the voice commands are different than the cards.

Comment: Agree with @wild_oscar. From what I know, the update is for Google Now Card, but not voice command. I also researched about this, and so far, there is no API for developer to integrate the voice command. There are 3rd-party apps (Commandr, Tasker+AutoVoice) that can add command to Google Now, but with current specification by OP, I think it's still impossible for SoundHound to identify a song directly.

Comment: @AndrewT.: Yes you are right. I searched about it too. Please edit this answer.